# Get details of pending transactions using web3.py

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, web3py

Please, help. How can I get details of pending transactions from the mempool by using web3.py? "filter('pending').get_all_entries" not work".

Comment: I have asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70234159/web3-valueerror-when-using-pending-filter), just in case it gets answered